# UIImage, CGImage, backing buffers and memory usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, uiimage, cgimage

I have a WebP image. Since there is no native iOS support for it I use libwebp to decode it into a `malloc`'d RGB buffer.

```
uint8_t *rgb = malloc(width * height * 3);
WebPDecode(rgb, ...);
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(rgb, size, ...);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, provider, ...);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

This works fine. However the images I'm working with are extremely large so the above code allocates a **lot** of memory and that `uint8_t *rgb` buffer will stick around as long as the image is being retained.

Now I also have a JPEG version of the exact same image. In it's encoded state the JPEG is about 30% larger than the WebP. Since iOS supports JPEG natively I can create a `UIImage` like this:

```
NSData *jpegData = ...;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:jpegData];
```

I'm not sure what `imageWithData:` does under the hood, but for some reason it only uses about 1/3 of the memory as the WebP image I created above (reported by Xcode, device and simulator).

**My question**: If I understand correctly, before you render an image to the screen at some point it has to be decoded into it's RGB components. If I am correct in this assumption, then shouldn't these 2 images take up the same amount of memory?

**Update**: Xcode does not seem to be reporting the **real** memory being used, but Instruments does. Profiling the app in Instruments I can see the same amount of memory allocated by `malloc` and `ImageIO_JPEG_Data`. Can anyone explain what Xcode's memory report is actually telling me? It seems wildly off.

Comment: iOS likes to be smart about memory management of `UIImage`s. If it is reading the data from a file in a natively-understood format, it just lets it sit in the file until it is told to draw on screen. If you have modified the data in any way since its load, it will keep the whole thing.

Comment: In my case I've loaded both of these images from the network. Neither were written to the disk and both were rendered on screen when I checked memory usage.

Comment: Technically you are right, they should have the same size... I'm not sure if there might be a problem somewhere in the WebP code, but you can easily check if memory usage is fine when using Jpeg, you should see in Instruments an ImageIO_jpeg_data (on simulator, might be something different on device, don't remember ATM) object with it's size equal to width*height*4 If that's the case, maybe the WebP part has some leaks or bad memory management somewhere...

Comment: The JPEG data you downloaded remains in its compressed JPEG format until the system is told to draw it. The fact that you didn't write them to disk is kind of irrelevant.

Comment: As I said, I did draw both of them to the screen. I updated my question, Xcode is not showing the correct memory usage. Instruments is.